# How to add hander within a thread?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, zip

I am zipping a file using the Ionic Class in VB. I wanted to report the save progress to the GUI. I handled the **zip.SaveProgress** event with **Sub ProgessChanged**. It worked on the main thread, but  I need to shift it to worker thread.

This is what I tied..

```
Dim foldertozip As String
Dim zipfileaddress As String

 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SelectFile_BT.Click
      Dim th As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf ZipUp)
      th.Start()
 End Sub

Public Sub ZipUp()
    Dim zip As ZipFile = New ZipFile
    AddHandler zip.SaveProgress, AddressOf ProgressUpdater

    zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestSpeed
    zip.BufferSize = My.Settings.BufferSize
    zip.AddDirectory(foldertozip)
    zip.Save(zipfileaddress)
End Sub


Public Shared Sub ProgressUpdater(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SaveProgressEventArgs)
    If (e.EventType = ZipProgressEventType.Saving_Completed) Then
        Return
    ElseIf (e.EventType = ZipProgressEventType.Saving_BeforeWriteEntry) Then
        Status.Label1.Text = e.CurrentEntry.FileName
    ElseIf (e.EventType = ZipProgressEventType.Saving_EntryBytesRead) Then
        Status.PercentLabel.Text = CStr(CInt(e.BytesTransferred) / (0.01 * e.TotalBytesToTransfer))
        Status.ProgressBar1.Value = CInt(CInt(e.BytesTransferred) / (0.01 * e.TotalBytesToTransfer))
    End If
End Sub
```

I am not much familiar with threading...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying, without actually saying, that you want to do the compressing on a secondary thread but handle the event on the UI thread? If so then you would just use the same `Invoke` method to execute the event handler on the UI thread as is used any time you want to execute a method on the UI thread in WinForms. The event is going to be raised on the secondary thread regardless.

```
Public Sub ProgressUpdater(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SaveProgressEventArgs)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New Action(Of Object, SaveProgressEventArgs)(AddressOf ProgressUpdater), sender, e)
    Else
        If (e.EventType = ZipProgressEventType.Saving_Completed) Then
            Return
        ElseIf (e.EventType = ZipProgressEventType.Saving_BeforeWriteEntry) Then
            Status.Label1.Text = e.CurrentEntry.FileName
        ElseIf (e.EventType = ZipProgressEventType.Saving_EntryBytesRead) Then
            Status.PercentLabel.Text = CStr(CInt(e.BytesTransferred) / (0.01 * e.TotalBytesToTransfer))
            Status.ProgressBar1.Value = CInt(CInt(e.BytesTransferred) / (0.01 * e.TotalBytesToTransfer))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that that method is not `Shared`, so that it can access members of the current instance.